# Oracle Python Use Select Result as Column Name in other select

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am using cx oracle module in python. I have two tables that looks like this:

1st table:

```
|  parameter   |   context  |
+--------------+------------+
|      a       |  column_1  | 
|      b       |  column_2  |
```

2nd:

```
|id|  column_1      |  column_2   |
+--+----------------+-------------+
| 1|  bla1          |  (NULL)     | 
| 2|  bla2          |  (NULL)     | 
| 3|  (NULL)        |  (nla1)     | 
| 4|  (NULL)        |  (nla2)     |
```

The input is:
`a, nla1` so how to create the query if I want to return `id = 3` from second table?

The table structures were already like this. I cannot change it.

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Was there a *question*?

Comment: hi i have editted the question

Answer (score 2):

> "the column_name is variable it can be column1 if parameter a but can be column2 if parameter b"

Writing such a statement is not possible with regular SQL: you'll need to go dynamic and that means PL/SQL. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317).

The simplistic implementation is like this:

```
create or replace function get_id is
     (p_param_col in varchar2
      , p_param_val in varchar2)
    return number
is
    l_col_name varchar2(30);
    return_value number;
begin
    select context into l_col_name
    from table_1
    where parameter = p_param_col;

    execute immediate 'select id from table_2 where '
            || l_col_name || ' = :1'
         into return_value
         using p_param_val;

   return return_value;
end;
```

Comment: is it better if i created a stored procedure for this? because this function/sp need to be called from python using cx oracle module

i believe it is more troublesome if create this in python script.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL to design a query in runtime and then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE clause.

Comment: how is this going to be done? do you mind to show example?

Comment: To not be repetitive, It's exactly as in APC answer. And it's not necessary to create a SP, you can write your query in anonimous block.